# 3 column bootstrap grid layout troubles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I am trying to set up a section of a website to have a column of text, a long vertical picture, and another column of text on the other side of the picture. I have been able to achieve the look I want but only by using a negative top margin(not shown in this example).

The code I have tried is here

http://www.bootply.com/3hKEyWGlJp

Comment: I can't see the issue. In your example you already have a "column of text, a long vertical picture, and another column of text". Please explain better if possible

Comment: @NunoArruda If you scroll down you can see that i have a step 3, and 4 that i would like to include as well, they appear under the grey div in the example.

Comment: I see that. Is the step 3 and 4 the issue? If yes, how do you want the step 3 and 4 to be displayed?

Comment: @NunoArruda Yes the issue is step 3, and 4, When i use a new row to add them they get pushed down below the grey div and the only way i have been able to fix it is to use a negative top margin on the div. 

I would like Step1/2 in the left column, div in the middle, and step 3/4 on the right side.

Comment: show us the before code where u were successful.

Comment: @crazymoin It was only a success in the sense it looked how i wanted it to look on a desktop computer. It broke entirely when re-sizing for responsiveness. so I scrapped it and moved on looking for the correct solution

Comment: problem is, it is hard to understand what u are asking about!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the extra row since a new row will create a new block below the previous row. It's how CSS grids work (Bootstrap in your example). Just put the content of step 1/2 in left column, div in center column and step 3/4 content in right column.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <p class="lead text-left">Step 1: asdf asdf asdf </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce blandit, dolor at..</p>

        <p class="lead">Step 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce blandit, dolor at</p>
    </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="phone"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p class="lead text-left">Step 3:Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
    <p>Start typing your address &amp; we will give you a list of options to choose from.</p>

    <p class="lead">Step 4: Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
    <p>dsadsdad sddasd saddsd dasdsada sdasds d ds ads dadsd dasd sada sdasdsdd sads dadsdda sdsada sdasdsd</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/rCr1B4wiKD